# What would be the correct action to exchange duplicates?

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions

Duplicates are an extremely useful on the way of finding an answer to some question. There is a common consensus, that the best question should be used as a duplicate target.

I just found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11107536/convert-string-to-type-in-c-sharp), answered extremely well by Jon. But the question is a duplicate of [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1825147/type-gettypenamespace-a-b-classname-returns-null).

The first Q & A pair seems to be more helpful. It gave me the solution I really wanted more quickly. While the other question has also correct answers, I needed to put more effort into it in order to extract the actual solution.

So I am wondering, if it would be a good idea to try to exchange the duplicates? If so, what would be the correct course of action to do so?

Comment: This is what frustrates me about duplicates - they usually have subtle differences that make merging them not a viable option (because context of answers may be lost).

Answer (score 1):

I don't think anything *should* happen here.

Looking at the older question, I'm able to surmise much of what's going on. The newer answer further validates the older answer, and it does so in a *slightly* clearer fashion.  However all of the raw bits are there; a studious person would be able to glean the same information from the earlier answers as they would the newer answers.

I don't see a reason to change the cardinality of the duplicate.  If the dupe is useful as a canonical, then there's little harm in closing questions as a dupe of *it*.

Comment: Sometimes its worth migrating an answer from one question to another, in the case where the dupe-target is a *good question* but the duplicate has the *good answer.*